# How can I scrape all links in vector of webpages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need to scrape all the attrs src from all the iframe containing 'fibalivestats.com' found inside the game links.

The initial url is fixture that stores all the links of the games.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import chromedriver_binary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get('https://www.argentina.basketball/tfb/fixture/de/division-buenos-aires')

partidos = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for partido in partidos:
    if partido.get_attribute('href').find('https://www.argentina.basketball/tfb/partido/') == 0:
        hrefs.append(partido.get_attribute("href"))
```

Then I separate the iframes doing a 'for' loop for the href that interests me, but some don't take all the links (this happens randomly)

```
hrefs=[]
fibalive=[]
errores=[]
j = 0
a = 0

for href in hrefs:
    browser.get(href)
    try:
        if browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe').get_attribute('src').find('https://www.fibalivestats.com/') == 0:
            fibalive.append(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe').get_attribute('src'))    
    except NoSuchElementException as exception:
        j = j + 1
        file = open('D:/Desktop/Partidos/partidos'+str(j)+'.txt',"w")
        file.write(browser.page_source)
        file.close()
```

When generating a .txt from the page_source of the links that generate the exception, the html is as follows:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: What's the exact issue here? can you explain what's going wrong and what you want to achieve.

Comment: The problem is that when I extract the iframe, randomly about 20 or more links throw the NoSuchElementException exception. I need to extract all the iframe none can be missing.

Comment: Running your code gives this error `ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'`. this means that the domain host detected automation and closed it. Does your test encounter this?

Comment: Not when I run my test everything works but as it goes through the links in some it makes the exception NoSuchElementException mentioned above